# Telling git to use my GPG Keychain on mac

Tags: macos, keychain, gnupg

While trying to follow the GitHub docs on GPG signing for the second time, I have somehow managed to fall off completely. What is strange is that I did this before several months without any trouble, but now just nothing works.

What I did was:

download gpgtools for mac as recommended by github (https://gpgtools.org/)

used the UI to create a gpg key (RSA 4096) with the same name and email as my github account (and ssh key).

Right click, copy. Pasted the result in a notes app. Saw that it looked like an armor whatchumacallit, exactly like what I would get using the gpg cli method. Pasted that into my profile's gpg key (github).

$ cat ~/.gitconfig

```
[user]
    name = ...
    email = ...
[commit]
    gpgsign = true
```

now, if I try and commit anything, I get:

```
error: gpg failed to sign the data:
gpg: skipped "[my email]": No secret key
[GNUPG:] INV_SGNR 9 [my email]
[GNUPG:] FAILURE sign 17
gpg: signing failed: No secret key

fatal: failed to write commit object
```

Thing is. My work laptop has the same gitconfig. There's no key mentioned there. None of my workdirs has a git config with the gpg-thingy.

Now, if I use the cli, create gpg key. Add the key id to my gitconfig, and force  `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` for whatever archaic reason, that works. BUT IT ASKS FOR THE PASSWORD EVERY TIME.

I removed that key's id from gitcofig. I don't want that option. **How tell use gpg keychain?** (which, just so we avoid a discussion, is up and running and has the key with the correct mail and everything that I did paste into github, just like the CLI gpg key).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, my bad. The error is just gibberish. What happened is that the git config name did not match. Even if the email did. The error is just essentially saying "Did not find a key matching NAME ". The key exists, it's in the keychain, but nothing matched the presented gitconfig. Error.

Fix is to just have the same name and mail in ~/.gitconfig.

Comment: Also, have a look at the locale of your signing key versus the system's set locale. My problem had exactly the same behavior, except that the encoding mismatch confused `git`. When switching to a matching locale in the shell, it worked.